# python3, I am getting the error "Can't assign to function call"

Tags: python-3.x, time, syntax-error

when I run my file, it says this:

```
for time.time() in range(int(x),int(x)+30):
       ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

I am trying to make it loop for 30 seconds

Here is some of the other parts of the code:

```
    x = time.time()
    print(x)
    for time.time() in range(int(x),int(x)+30):
        print(a)
        a = a + 1
```

If someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you want the code to actually do.  As written it doesn't really seem to make sense.

Comment: In short, the thing following `for` has to be a variable, so that Python can assign to it the successive values that you're iterating over.  `time.time()` isn't a variable, it's a function call, and it can't be assigned to.  So what you've written has no meaning.

Comment: I am trying to get it to wait 30 seconds until stopping the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for item in range(10):

means that you are counting from 0-10, assigning a number to the variable called 'item'. It has an error as you can't assign a value to a function. The function (time.time) returns a value and cannot be assigned a value.

```
x0 = time.time()
a=0
while (time.time() - x0 <30):
   print(a)
   a=a+1
```

Comment: how could I make it loop for 30 seconds?

Comment: use a while loop instead to check if cond still true. time.time() to get the current time minus x0, time of program start. @Supergamer5465